# How to load Html file from assets folder into WebView

Tags: java, android

I have tried a couple of things to get this issue worked out including examples i found on the web but no to avail. It displays absolutely nothing. Below are my codes.
Please help me i don't know where i get it wrong

And i have internet permission in my AndroidMainfest.xml:
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/tv01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
public class LocalDialogActivity extends Activity {

    protected WebView webView;
    private static final String URL = "file:///assets/dancerkate.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.local_tv01);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

        webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);


        refreshWebView(webView);

    }

    public void refreshWebView(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
```

Comment: Replace `private static final String URL = "file:///assets/dancerkate.html";` with:    `private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/dancerkate.html";` Also, make sure that either there is no JavaScript in that HTML file, or you will need to also enable JavaScript in your `WebView`.

Comment: I Enabled JavaScript still no solution.      WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }

Comment: Ok, it is showing the text now. How do i set the text to 20sp and remove the zoom effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All thanks to **@CommonsWare** for providing me with this wonderful solution
I made this answer for others who have this type of problem.
It is working now. This is exactly how i put it to work

```
    protected WebView webView;
    private static final String URL = "file:///android_asset/dancerkate.html";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.local_tv01);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }



        refreshWebView(webView);

    }

    public void refreshWebView(View view) {
        webView.loadUrl(URL);
    }
```